# .Net Core, Setting Response Content-Type to a Vendor Specific Media Type

Tags: api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on a simple .NET Core API with several endpoints.

I need to return the Content-Type in my Request as a vendor specific Media Type, "application/vnd.com.myhomepay.api.ste.location-code+json". However, whenever I set the Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.com.myhomepay.api.ste.location-code+json"), I get a 406 Status Code returned with the Response. I have read where I need to add this custom MediaTypeHeaderValue to the list of SupportedMediaTypes but I can't figure out how to do this in .Net Core. Any tips or suggestions for accomplishing this. I have also read about a more complicated approach using IOutputFormatter.

Each endpoint will have it's own vendor specific notation that will be passed back in the Response's Content-Type Header.

Option 1 that I tried:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
         options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("application/json", "application/vnd.com.myhomepay.api.ste.location-code+json;version=1");
         options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("application/json", "application/vnd.com.myhomepay.api.ste.tax-calculation+json;version=1");
    });
}
```

Controller.cs

```
  [Produces("application/vnd.com.myhomepay.api.ste.location-code+json;version=1")]
  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult Get()
  {
      DailyReportAbbreviated dailyreport;
      .....
      return new OkObjectResult(dailyreport);
  }
```

Request "Accept" header set to "application/vnd.com.myhomepay.api.ste.location-code+json;version=1"

This returns Status Cod 406 Not Acceptable

Option 2:

I just removed the "Produces" attribute from the controller and added:

Controller.cs

```
  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult Get()
  {
      DailyReportAbbreviated dailyreport;
      .....
      Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.com.myhomepay.api.ste.location-code+json");
      return new OkObjectResult(dailyreport);
  }
```

This returns Status Cod 406 Not Acceptable

Option 3:

This option appears to be working

Starup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new JsonOutputFormatter()); 
    });
}
```

JsonOutputFormatter.cs

```
public class JsonOutputFormatter : IOutputFormatter
{
    public bool CanWriteResult(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context)
    {
         return true;
    }

    public async Task  WriteAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
    {
         if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
         var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
         //context.ContentType returns the string set on the "Produces" attribute that is set on the controller
         response.ContentType = context.ContentType.ToString();
         using (var writer = context.WriterFactory(response.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
         {
             await writer.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Object));
         }
    }
}
```

Controller.cs

```
  [Produces("application/vnd.com.myhomepay.api.ste.location-code+json;version=1")]
  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult Get()
  {
      DailyReportAbbreviated dailyreport;
      .....
      return new OkObjectResult(dailyreport);
  }
```

Comment: thanks for asking this question, and providing your own findings. Are you still using solution 3? I'm wondering what the best method will be for returning the Json Api spec media type: "application/vnd.api+json". Ref: https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-objects